# Is it possible to Create custom album in IOS 6

Tags: uiimagepickercontroller, alassetslibrary

Can any one tell me.. I want to work with Camera Application now so I have to know Is it possible to create custom album in IOS 6. I know it is possible in IOS5 then I searched it for IOS6
I did not get any clear information..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.  The method you want is the `ALAssetsLibrary` method `addAssetsGroupAlbumWithName:resultBlock:failureBlock:` which is detailed in the docs here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetsLibrary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/ALAssetsLibrary

It was introduced in iOS 5 and has not since been deprecated, so I'm not quite sure what the issue is if it's not working for you.  You may have to update or repost the question if you are having trouble with it.

Comment: Thank you very much.. Its working fine..  I have another questions on it Can we Delete the image in the Custom album..? after sending it to the server and while sending image to server it adds some noise data to the image data so it will not displayed the image in the browser.. Why could it happens tell me "How to resolve it"..

Comment: No, apps cannot delete photos from the library (for fairly obvious reasons, I think).  If you need to store an image temporarily and then remove it, you should use `NSFileManager` not `ALAssetsLibrary`.  I don't really understand the second part of your question.  I think you'd do better to post a new question that clearly shows the problem you're experiencing.

Comment: Finally I did some changes in the code like removed some data in the image data then image is displayed in the browser..

Comment: in iOS 6 how can save image in a custom album? Thanks

Comment: @milonet: Your best bet is to add a new question that shows us what you tried and describes your exact problem. If you haven't read the docs, the normal case is to use addAsset:, so perhaps you can start there. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetsGroup_Class/Reference/Reference.html